# change font color of Shiny dropdown header (selectInput)

Tags: r, shiny

I've seen a few posts on changing the color of the actual drop down items to select and many seem to need lengthy CSS calls and files. What if the only formatting change we want is to change font color of certain drop down headers or portions of drop down headers, like `Select Breakfast`, or just `Breakfast`, to say, purple?

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(input$user_choice1))
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

column( width = 5,
selectInput("user_choice1",
"Select Breakfast",
choices = c("good", "better", "amazing"), selected = "amazing") ) ,
column( width = 5,
selectInput("user_choice2",
"Select Dinner",
choices = c("bad", "mediocre", "ok"), selected = "ok")  ,


mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to apply changes to a single word in label then the easiest is to pass a raw html string doing what you want. Note that it will still inherit properties from `label`

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  column( width = 5,
          selectInput("user_choice1",
                      shiny::HTML("<p>Select <span style='color: purple'>Breakfast</span></p>"),
                      choices = c("good", "better", "amazing"), selected = "amazing") ) ,
  column( width = 5,
          selectInput("user_choice2",
                      "Select Dinner",
                      choices = c("bad", "mediocre", "ok"), selected = "ok")  ,


          mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

How does this suit? You can see I've used minimal CSS and IDs to specify which column I want to make changes to:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny) 
library(tableHTML)

 server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
     hist(rnorm(input$user_choice1))
   })
 }

 ui <- fluidPage(

   column(id = "columns", width = 5,
           selectInput("user_choice1",
                       "Select Breakfast",  
                       choices = c("good", "better", "amazing"), selected = "amazing") ) ,
   column( width = 5,
           selectInput("user_choice2",
                       "Select Dinner",  
                       choices = c("bad", "mediocre", "ok"), selected = "ok")  ,


           mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))),


   tags$style(make_css(list('#columns', 
                            c('font-size', 'font-family', 'color'), 
                            c('15px', 'calibri light', 'red'))))

   )

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```